# Python string comparison whilst in loop

Tags: python, string, loops, comparison, match

I am both new to this forum & programming & Python. I am trying to develop my first program, however I keep coming up against a brick wall regarding one particular issue. I am hopng that some kind sole can put me out of my misery & show me how to do what I want to do correctly. I'm sure it's simple if you know what you are doing, but at the moment I am stupid & do not have a clue what I'm doing :-)

Example:

I need to work with 2 files, A & B

File A contains the text:

```
This is a test
```

While file B contains the text:

```
h
t
s
i
a
```

I need to create a program that will grab 1 character at a time from file A and then search through file B looking for an identical character. Once the program has found a match, I want it to print the row number where it found the match, then move on grab another character from file A & repeat this process until EOF.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! You've chosen an interesting challenge (congratulations!) and you've described it well. However, you didn't say at all where you're stuck - reading a file, iterating over it, taking substrings, comparing them... Could you show what you've written so far? Then it's easier for us to give you specific advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, let's take this one step at a time. First, I would read file `B` into a structure that's well suited for fast lookup since we're going to be doing that quite often:

```
chars = {}
with open("B") as lookupfile:
    for number,line in enumerate(lookupfile):
        chars[line.strip()] = number
```

Now we have a dictionary `chars` that contains letters as keys and their row number as values:

```
>>> chars
{'t': 1, 'a': 4, 'i': 3, 'h': 0, 's': 2}
```

Now we can iterate over the first file. The standard Python iterator for files consumes one *line*  per iteration, not one *character*, so it's probably best to simply read the entire file into a string and then iterate over that (because for strings, iteration is character-by-character):

```
with open("A") as textfile:
    text = textfile.read()
```

Now we iterate over the string and print matching values:

```
for char in text:
    if char in chars:
        print("Character {0} found in row {1}".format(char, chars[char]))
```

If you don't like accessing the dictionary twice, you can also use

```
for char in text:
    found = chars.get(char):    # returns None if char isn't a key in chars
    if found:
        print("Character {0} found in row {1}".format(char, found))
```

or, using exceptions:

```
for char in text:
    try:
        print("Character {0} found in row {1}".format(char, chars[char]))
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Comment: Hi Tim, really appreciate your help on this. Tried out your code & it works perfectly. I just need to modify now to suit my own little program. I'll also spend some time studying your code, so that I can learn from it for the future. Thanks again! Clinton.

Answer (score 0):

Read the file `A` first and store it's content in a variable(using `file.read`).

```
with open('A.txt') as f:

    data = f.read()  # now data is: "This is a test"
    # now data is string that dontains all data of the file A.
    # But as searching a character in a string is an O(N) operation
    # so we must convert this string to a better data-structure.
    # As we need the item as well as their first index so we
    # should create a dict here, with character as the key and
    # it's first appearance(first index) as it's value. 
    # Dicts provide O(1) lookup.

    dic = {}
    for ind, char in enumerate(data):
        # store the character in dict only if it is an alphabet
        # also check if it's already present is dict or not.
        if char.isalpha() and char not in dic:
            dic[char] = ind
    #dic is {'a': 8, 'e': 11, 'i': 2, 'h': 1, 's': 3, 'T': 0, 't': 10}
```

Now open the file `B` and iterate over it using a for-loop, a for-loop over an file iterator returns one line at a time.(memory efficient approach).

```
with open('B.txt') as f:
    for char in f:            #iterate one line at a time 
        char = char.strip()   #str.strip strips off whitespaces like '\n'
        if char in dic:
           print dic[char]     # if character is found in dict then
                              # print it's value, i.e index
...             
1
10
3
2
8
```

Comment: Hi Ashwini,thanks for all your help. I have tried your option, also the option below by Tim. Unfortunately when I tried out your code there were some errors & nothing really happen. so rather than try & work out what was wrong I tried Tim's code which worked perfectly. Thanks for your help though! I do really appreciate it :-)

Comment: @user2490853 what errors exactly? I fixed a typo now it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
fA = open('C:\\Desktop\\fileA.txt', 'r')
fB = open('C:\\Desktop\\fileB.txt', 'r')

fileb_content = []
for line in fB:
    fileb_content.append(fB.read().split('\n'))

rA = fA.readline().split('\n')[0]

for c in list(rA):
        if(c.strip()):
            if(c.lower() in fileb_content[0]):
                print(fileb_content[0].index(c.lower()))
```

here i test that character is not empty.

Comment: Hi antitrust, thanks for your input & time. All sorted now after trying the code from another person who kindly replied. Clinton.